# Session management for reactjs application

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What is the best way/approach to manage the **session** for a **reactjs** application.

I have been through multiple links but haven't figured out a way to manage the session.

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: JSON web token. I guess you are talking about user login session. If so I was in same situation when I started my React application. Finally I ended up with using Json web token it’s simply called JWT. It’s very easy and carry’s simple steps to configure.

Comment: Can you send me any link where i can get the steps to configure...

Comment: You could start with this: https://auth0.com/blog/reactjs-authentication-tutorial